# mapping (different)XML(formats) to a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd, mapping

how can i map xml file(s) of different formats to a table in my database say for example i have a table called `Person`

```
FirstName nvarchar(50),
LastName nvarchar(50),
Address  nvarchar(500)
```

i have to map xml files submitted by users to the fields of `Person`, the xml files can be in different formats say for example one user submits in the following format

```
<Person>

<Names>
<FirstName>john</FirstName>
<LastName>smith</LastName>
</Names>

<Names>
<FirstName>john</FirstName>
<LastName>smith</LastName>
</Names>


</Person>
```

and another user submits it in the following format

```
<Person>
<PersonalInfo>

<Names>
<FirstName>john</FirstName>
<LastName>smith</LastName>
</Names>
.
.
.
<PersonalInfo>
</Person>
```

how can i device a solution that will handle different cases (different xml formats), so that if a user submits a xml file in whatever format i just have to tell the format to my aplication and its values will automatically gets mapped to the said table... im using visual studio 2010 as an IDE and C#.NET, i hope have narrated the problem well enough...

please advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't how dynamic this should be (meaning how often you will change the mappings) or how many different XMLs do u have I will suggest you to map the table(s) to a common class using your preferred ORM and create class instances using LinqToXml (which is very easy). One method or class per XML structure.

There is a sample here for the LinqToXml -> http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing

Also, if you don´t want to use it and are using .NET 4 I created a simple library to produce dynamic objects from a XML string. You can take a look at it here -> https://github.com/tucaz/XmlToObjectParser

Answer (score 1):

1. you can identify the schema you are acquiring and use appropriate XSLT File to convert it to the latest version.
   **Note**: you should make something generic to identify the schema (e.g. )
2. (I Like 1. better) create an Software Adapter interface that changes the mappings (Like add-ins work)